# Can't find Objective C file

Tags: objective-c, swift4, jbchartview

So I'm not to up on Objective-C so I apologize if this is a basic question but I can't seem to find someone with my exact problem.
I added the JBChartView(written in Objective-C) Cocoapod to a Swift project. The chart is good to go and fully up and running. However I then added some other separate Objective-C files and when trying to import a file from JBChartView it can't be found. What gives, I can access this Objective-C library from Swift files but not Objective-C files. Any ideas?

Below is everything I have tried.

```
#import "JBChartView.h"
#import <JBChartView/JBChartView.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really give us much to go on here, but if you're able to import the framework successfully using Swift, then the framework is probably defining a module. In this case, you can just take the `import` statement you're using in Swift, add a `@` to the beginning of it and `;` to the end of it and you've got a module import for Objective-C. So, if the import in Swift looks like:

```
import JBChartView
```

then you can do this in Objective-C:

```
@import JBChartView;
```

The mechanism is the same in both cases, so if one works, the other should too.